# Argument Dependent Lookup is not working as expected

Tags: c++, templates, argument-dependent-lookup

I just tried to test Argument Dependent Lookup in Visual C++ 2013:

```
#include <utility>
#include <string>

struct X {};

int main (int argc, char* argv [])
{
    std::string s1;
    std::string s2 = move (s1); // succeed

    X a;
    X b = move (a); // Failed?!

    return 0;
}
```

I have included the `utility` header directly, but it is not working as expected!

Is Argument Dependent Lookup always guarantied to work?

Comment: How do you expect it to work and why? ADL is always guaranteed to work as specified in the C++ standard.

Comment: Why did the second `move` fail?

Comment: Why would it not fail? `move` has not been declared in that scope, and there is no ADL, because `X` is not in the `std` namespace.

Comment: I think you don't know what ADL actually means. Look it up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is working as expected :

- In the first case, ADL works because `move` is looked up in `std::`, since the argument is `std::string`.
- In the second case, `X` is in the global namespace, there is no matching `move` function there, so ADL finds nothing.

If `X` is declared within `std::` (it shouldn't, its undefined behavior...), ADL works as expected :

```
namespace std { struct X {}; } 

int main (int argc, char* argv [])
{
    std::string s1;
    std::string s2 = move (s1); // succeed

    std::X a;
    std::X b = move (a); // succeed

    return 0;
}
```